# Proteger rutas con passport laravel y Dingo Api

Tags: laravel-5, api

He buscado como proteger las rutas de laravel a través de mi Api con Dingo encontré un ejemplo pero no creo que sea el adecuado acá el [link](https://github.com/dingo/api/issues/1159#issuecomment-248687864)
Si alguno conoce otra forma de hacer desde Dingo Api como se hace aca usando la libreria desde Jwt donde la librería esta integrada al archivo config/api.php

```
JSON Web Tokens (JWT)

This package makes use of a 3rd party package to integrate JWT authentication. Please refer to the tymon/jwt-auth GitHub page for details on installing and configuring the package.

Once you have the package you can configure the provider in your config/api.php file or in a service provider or bootstrap file.

'auth' => [
    'jwt' => 'Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\JWT',
],
app('Dingo\Api\Auth\Auth')->extend('jwt', function ($app) {
   return new Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\JWT($app['Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth']);
});
```

Comment: ¿Por qué está Passport en el título? No parece que lo estés usando según dices en el post.

Comment: Si lo estoy usando lo que quiero es proteger las rutas con passport a la hora de que un usuario o maquina necesite hacer solicitudes al servicio Api uso Dingo Api y Passport para mantener la Autenticación por medio de Tokens pero al usar https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/passport#protecting-routes me da un unauthorized 401 en el ejemplo que coloque arriba este https://github.com/dingo/api/issues/1159#issuecomment-248687864 Dice como integrar passport con dingoApi el cual no creo que sea lo correcto verificar si un usuario esta autorizado a dicha petición por medio de request @GerardReches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final de tanto luchar pude hacer que Passport me funcionara con Dingo Api para mis Apis-Rest dejo el código si alguno lo necesita y pueda hacerle de ayuda y pueda mejorarlo y hacerlo mas eficiente y correcto

Archivo GuardServiceProvider.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: vdjke
 * Date: 10/28/2016
 * Time: 6:31 p.m.
 */

namespace App\Providers;
use Dingo\Api\Routing\Route;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager;
use Dingo\Api\Auth\Provider\Authorization;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\UnauthorizedHttpException;

/**
 * Class GuardServiceProvider
 * @package App\Providers
 */
class GuardServiceProvider extends Authorization
{

    /**
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard|\Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected $auth;


    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $guard = 'api';


    /**
     * GuardServiceProvider constructor.
     * @param AuthManager $auth
     */
    public function __construct(AuthManager $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth->guard($this->guard);
    }


    /**
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Route $route
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable|null
     */
    public function authenticate(Request $request, Route $route)
    {
        if (! $user = $this->auth->user()) {
            throw new UnauthorizedHttpException(
                get_class($this),
                'Invalid API key and token.'
            );
        }

        return $user;
    }


    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthorizationMethod()
    {
        return 'Bearer';
    }
}
```

En su Kernel.php

```
'api' => [
            'auth:api',
            'api.auth',
            'throttle:60,1',
            'bindings',
        ],
```

Uso del middleware en sus archivos de las rutas

```
$api->group(['middleware' => ['api']], function($api){
            $api->get('stream', 'ApiStreamController@index');
        });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero les sirva de algo y les sea de utilidad